# MySql select statement with echo variable

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I have mysql database with two tables. The primary table contains the user login details and the secondary table contains user activities. The tables are linked by the account numbers.

I have created registration page and sign in page where users register and login. Users are displayed with a home page with two buttons.

When users clicked on the button, it is supposed to run a query based on the user login credentials. The query looks like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("select mydate, preamount, currentdeposit,
debit, currentinterest, totalamount, status  from NormalAccount where
acctnumber = '$actno'n ORDER BY mydate DESC LIMIT 5");
```

Because I need to filter based on the user account number, I have design a form where they will need to enter their account number again. This makes the whole process looks like double work and users are complaining about the whole process of entering information twice.

WHAT I WANT:

How do I write the query such that the query will populate the user credentials automatically so that they need not to enter their account number again before viewing their account details?

I have a session on the pages already that enables me to pull and display the user details on the page using echo such as echo acctname where it display the account name of the user in any part of the page.

I used the php with echo below to automatically display a welcome message to the users using the account name automatically. How to I integrate this code below

```
<?php echo $userRow['acctname']; ?>
```

into the WHERE clause in the main query so that it automatically populate the account name for the users so that it will filter the record based on their acctname?

I have a session on each page with this code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require_once 'dbconnect.php';
if( !isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
header("Location: index.php");
exit;
}
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userss WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
?>
```

Thanks.

Zollyzo

Comment: Use sessions....

Comment: And don't use `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: Why don't you store account number in session or cookie variable in login page and use it in account summary page.

Comment: I have session on each page that looks like this

Comment: I have a session page that looks like this [<?php
 ob_start();
 session_start();
 require_once 'dbconnect.php';
 
 // if session is not set this will redirect to login page
 if( !isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
  header("Location: index.php");
  exit;
 }
 // select loggedin users detail
 $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userss WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user']);
 $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
?>]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that I understand the problem, but the first time that you ask for the account number, you could store it in the $_SESSION variable the first time you receive it from the user. Then, you could just retrieve it later, even if it's on a different page.

```
<?php
session_start();
...
//you get the account number somehow in $actno
$_SESSION['acctNr'] = $actno
...
//later in your code, or on another page that has had session_start() run
$actno = $_SESSION['acctNr']
//use it as you would before.
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user has logged in successfully, save their account number (and maybe other details) in a session variable. You can use that session variable for your succeeding queries so you don't need to ask the users to enter their account number again.

Basic usage: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp